# Racket’s SXpath: from an XPath string to the “idiomatic way”

Tags: xpath, scheme, racket, sxml

I am working on extracting information from an HTML page in racket.

To do so, I use the [html-parsing](https://docs.racket-lang.org/html-parsing/index.html) and [sxml](http://docs.racket-lang.org/sxml/SXML.html) packages.

I want to select an element in the page with a particular id. I currently use a plain XPath expression to do so:

```lisp
(require sxml)

(define expression
  '(test (div (@ (id "foo") 
                 (other-attr "bar"))
              first-div-content) 
         (div (@ (id "baz") 
                 (other-attr "quux"))
              second-div-content)))

(define wanted-result
  '((div (@ (id "foo") (other-attr "bar"))
         first-div-content)))

(equal? ((sxpath "//div[@id='foo']") expression)
        wanted-result)

; ==> #t
```

However, as the documentation says:

> The txpath function accepts the standard XPath syntax, whereas the sxpath function is structured in a more idiomatic (for Racket) way.

So, I would like to express the same path as an s-expression. And while it is easy from the examples given to turn `"//div"` into `'(// div)`, I did not find how to query specific attributes. I gather that I would have to use an `sxml-converter` or `sxml-converter-as-predicate`, but don’t know how to do so.

I know that the xpath version works very well and maybe I should not bother using s-expressions, but I want to understand how it works and then decide for myself what version to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that particular xpath is written as

```
(sxpath '(// (div (@ id (equal? "foo"))))))
```

The sxpath element `(div (@ id (equal? "foo")))` has the form `(sxpath-or-symbol reducer-path ...)`, which means select the elements matching`sxpath-or-symbol` that also have non-empty matches for each `reducer-path`. The rewriting rules in the documentation of [`sxpath`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/sxml/sxpath.html#(def._((lib._sxml%2Fmain..rkt)._sxpath))) are intended to convey this idea, but they could use more examples.

Attributes are generally treated as if they were child elements of a `@` node.

Comment: `'(// (div (@ id (equal? "foo"))))` doesn’t work, but put me in the right track. In fact, the `//` and the `div` must be in the same list (not a sub-list), and the `id` must be in a sub-list, like so: `'(// div (@ (id (equal? "foo"))))`. Is it possible to edit your post to reflect this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wait, no, it doesn’t work as expected. It returns only the `@` node, not the full `div`. I’ll edit the question so that the expected behaviour is more obvious.

Comment: And now I feel very dumb. With trial and error and generating the converters by hand (directly writing `node-join`, `select-kids` and such), I found a solution that works… And it is yours…! I must have failed when testing the first time. And coming back to post this result, I find that you tested again… Sorry for the inconvenience. I’ll accept your answer, of course, as it is the correct one. At least I gained a better understanding of the system when trying to find a correction… :-S